# Flutter unable to load image assets (Loading images through ListView.builder)

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to load from the `assets/images` folder using `Listview.builder()` but it keeps throwing this error:

> EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE
> The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
> Unable to load asset: assets/images/image_1.png

I have also tried the `flutter clean` method, but to no avail.

Project structure is

```
lib
 |- home.dart
 |- main.dart
assets
 |- images
     |- image_1.png
     |- image_2.png
     |- ...
     |- image_10.png
pubspec.yaml
```

home.dart

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  // --snip--
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // --snip--
      body: Listview.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
          Image.asset('assets/images/image_${index + 1}.png', fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
        itemCount: controller.imageCount,
      ),
      // --snip--
    )
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```yaml
flutter:
  use-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Edit:

Screenshot of project directory from /
[(I'm not allowed to embed images yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecpNA.png)

Screenshot of project directory from /assets/images/
[And here in, lies my mistake.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA0iQ.png)

Comment: try adding an `itemCount`

Comment: Can you run `ls` in your project directory and inside _images_ directory in your terminal and show the output? (if you are using an Unix based system)

Comment: @fsbelinda Thank you for your comment, I have followed your advice and double checked the images and, yep, I forgot to the extract the .png files out, I still originally had the .jpg files that I confused to be .png file. I have also put the screenshots through the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

itemCount: controller.imageCount.length

and

- assets/images/image_1.png